# how to count the rows in cassandra column family

Tags: cassandra, hector

I'm writing a file with user profiles into cassandra with 5M profiles.
My write operation finished sucessfully.
I want to count the number of rows in my column family.

```
Keyspace keyspaceOperator = HFactory.createKeyspace(KEY_SPACE, cluster);
CqlQuery<String,String,Long> cqlQuery = new CqlQuery<String,String,Long>(keyspaceOperator, se, se, new LongSerializer());
cqlQuery.setQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM up");
QueryResult<CqlRows<String,String,Long>> result = cqlQuery.execute();
System.out.println(result.get().getAsCount());
```

But the following code prints me always 10000.
What am I doing wrong? And how can I make this operation from cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't for now.   There's a default limit of 10K rows per query.  There's an open ticket for this (CASSANDRA-3702) but no fix as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

Only other alternative is to iterate via RangeSlicesQuery. I created a "census" program to count both rows and total columns; [here's a version for long types](http://pastebin.com/h5zAUGsk). But, if this is a frequent activity, conventional wisdom seems to be to use a separate counter column to keep track; [some discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406178/counting-columns-very-slow-countquery-vs-slicequery-operations).

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to give a limit that's as large as you want to count. If you don't expect the count ever to go over 1e9, then do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM up LIMIT 1000000000;
```

But be aware that COUNT (and RangeSlicesQuery too) are not at all performant, or even meant to be. They're essentially the same as a "sequential scan" in relational db parlance. A counter is a better way to address this sort of problem in a distributed system.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [here](https://github.com/kkopalle/cassandraAstyanax) for an example that does this.

You can freely use the code. Please note that `Astyanax` has been branched out of `Hector` and we are finding that it is a very good `Cassandra` client in `Java`.